# alexa built in slot AMAZON.DATE does not recognize certain date formats.

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Alexa in the simulator does not recognize dates like these below,

18th june, 3 weeks from now, 25th june 2017, 25 jun

It does work with today, tomorrow.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

amazon dates have a specific format, so try using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format, or have some code in the background to convert between different formats